# XLOOKUP Function Disappeared

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-365

I have been using xlookup for several months across several files just fine but today it stopped working across all Excel files. I invested a lot of effort moving from vlookup to xlookup and now it's all broken. It returns the error "#NAME?" and it looks like the function is missing in the formula builder. How do I add the function?

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Have you tried to repair Office?

Comment: Please go to File > Account > Product Information, check the Office product name, version number and update channel. If it is Microsoft 365 apps, please make sure it is updated to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

XLookup is only part of Office365 subscriber licenses. If you have switched to a different license, or somehow your office is not activated anymore, you will lose a few Office365 only functions too, including xlookup.

If your license is still valid, try to repair your office installation or update it.